# Keep one item centred and the other to the right if there's enough space with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

In flexbox how do I keep one item centred and the other floated on the right if there's enough space, with flexbox.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried. As currently written, this question doesn't adhere to SO guidelines and may be closed. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See boxes #62-67 here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276